# Prove that $\sum^{n}_{k=0}(x-\frac{k}{n})^{2}{{n}\choose{k}}x^{k}(1-x)^{n-k}=\frac{x(1-x)}{n}$ holds for ${0}\leq{x}\leq{1}$

Tags: combinatorics

For ${0}\leq{x}\leq{1}$, prove that the following identity holds:$$\sum^{n}_{k=0}(x-\frac{k}{n})^{2}{{n}\choose{k}}x^{k}(1-x)^{n-k}=\frac{x(1-x)}{n}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have you tried anything and can share? regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the identity $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left(x-\frac{k}{n}\right)^2 \binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}=\frac{1}{n}x(1-x)$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565423/prove-the-identity-sum-limits-k-0n-leftx-frackn-right2-binomnk)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Write $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nkx^ky^{n-k}$$

Differentiate with respect to $x$, multiply by $x$, set $y=1-x$. Repeat. You will get expressions for $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nkkx^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nkk^2x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$

Then, it is a matter of putting things together.

**SPOILER** One can actually show, by the same token, that

> $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{{\left( {\alpha  - \frac{k}{n}} \right)}^2}\binom nk{x^k}{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^{n - k}}}  = {\left( {x - \alpha } \right)^2} + \frac{{x\left( {1 - x} \right)}}{n}$$

whence letting $x=\alpha$ gives what you want.

I cannot avoid mentioning the above plays a major role in an elementary proof of Weiertrass' approximation theorem using the Bernstein polynomials

$$K_{n,k}(x)=\binom nkx^k(1-x)^k$$